# а тебя () раз () и выбросят в мусорную кучу

Tags: пунктуация

*Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя () раз () и выбросят в мусорную кучу.* Какие знаки пунктуации нужны в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно подумать, что это междометный выкрик, но скорее всего здесь "раз" выступает в роли сказуемого (*Мальчишка раз яблоко - и бежать! Он раз по спине.*), в таком случае, соответственно, перед "раз" никакого знака не требуется, так как тут оно связано в дополнением "тебя" (раз кого? - тебя).
Следующее сказуемое тоже связано с этим дополнением (выбросят тебя), так что и тут знак препинания не нужен:

> Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя раз и выбросят в мусорную
>   кучу.

Но здесь чувствуется пауза, а ее можно обозначить при помощи тире:

> Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя раз - и выбросят в мусорную
>   кучу.

Answer (score 1):

> *Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя () раз () и выбросят в мусорную кучу.*
>
> Какие знаки пунктуации нужны в этом предложении?

Возможные варианты:

*Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя раз — и выбросят в мусорную кучу!*

*Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя  —  раз!  —  и выбросят в мусорную кучу.*

Comment: Вариант, предложенный slava1947, мне кажется самым верным:

Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, а тебя — раз! — и выбросят в мусорную кучу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вырастешь сорной травой, **а тебя раз ― и выбросят в мусорную кучу.**

**Из словаря:** РАЗ, в функц. сказ. Разг. Обозначает быстрое, неожиданное действие, выполняемое в один приём. Он раз по спине. **Громкий стук и раз ― дверь распахнулась.** Мальчишка раз яблоко ― и бежать!